# Android NDK (with SDL) build infrastructure clarification

Tags: java, build, android-ndk, sdl

I'm relatively new to building stuff with Android, Java, NDK, and SDL. But I've been futzing around in an example project I'm building and there's a lot that I find very confusing.

Here's a printout of my file structure- for reference:

```
MyProj
-android-project      //I created this to dump android-specific junk into
--src                 //java source files
--jni                 //"java native interface" - c/c++ source files
--AndroidManifest.xml //packaged with .apk to inform OS of various details of app
--bin                 //binary files?
---AndroidManifest.xml //Copy of AndroidManifest.xml in above dir?
---AndroidManifest.xml.d
---SDLActivity-debug-unaligned.apk
---SDLActivity-debug-unaligned.apk.d
---SDLActivity-debug.apk
---SDLActivity.ap_
---SDLActivity.ap_.d
---build.prop
---classes
---classes.dex
---classes.dex.d
---dexedLibs
---proguard.txt
---res
---rsLibs
---rsObj
--gen                 //no idea
--libs                //no idea
--obj                 //no idea
--res                 //no idea
--build.xml           //points to files regarding build config
--default.properties  //auto-generated?
--local.properties    //auto-generated?
--project.properties  //auto-generated?
```

So, I have a few specific questions, but if I'm wrong about any assumptions or there's a tidbit of info that you think I might be missing I'd really appreciate hearing about it!

Anyways-

**The 'bin' folder:**

I'd assume "bin" is for binaries... right? But it seems like it isn't. It contains a copy of AndroidManifest.xml (why?), a couple other text-y things, my project's .apk, and a bunch of folders I also don't understand. It also has a bunch of copies of things with '.d' appended to it ('AndroidManifest.xml.d', for example). Why? <strike>Also, if I wipe this folder, ndk-build fails. So it seems like there are build-relevant config files in here?</strike> *(edit: this was due to a faulty makefile on my part- thank god too. that part REALLY didn't make sense...)* I guess my questions are these: *What is the role of the bin folder? What are the .d files? What files are safe to delete (get generated during build)?*

**'gen', 'libs', 'obj', 'res' folders:**

A high level overview of what is going on with these would be helpful as well. :) Also, what of these is safe for deletion (gets auto generated during build)?

*edit:* 
upon further experimentation, it appears 'gen' can safely be wiped and will get auto re-*gen*erated during the build process.

I think it's safe to assume 'libs' cannot be safely cleared, but still fuzzy on exactly what it does.

looks like 'obj' CAN also safely be cleared- though it will require a longer build process, compiling all the SDL code and such. Appears to contain intermediate build files for SDL.

'res' CANNOT be safely cleared. still no idea what is in it/what it does.

**The *.properties files**

If these are auto-generated, why are they at the root of the project? I'm assuming they're some intermediate file of the build process?

*edit:* they all *say* they're auto-generated, but it appears they CANNOT be deleted or else the build process will fail. It will tell you to auto-generate stuff regarding the 'sdk.dir' (what?) using 'android update-project' (but stackoverflow searches tell you to use 'android update project -s -t "android-19" -p .', but that won't work either because of an invalid target, so I should type 'android list targets' to find out the targets but that list is empty and ughhh. so I just re checked those files out via git and it works again. so yeah- still no idea what they are, how they're generated, why they are where they are, etc...

**TL;DR:**

It feels like this whole build infrastructure is absurdly unclear / overcomplicated. What pieces am I missing that might help all of this *click*?

I guess if there are any good sources of documentation / explanation of what the heck is going on with all this I would love to be directed to it. Most of the stuff I've found takes the form of "oh, you want to build something for android? Well, click here, then here, then here, and there you go! It's built!", where I'd rather have something that tells me what is going on and why / how.

Sorry this post is a bit rambly- answers to any of the questions/pointers to any resources for further learning would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"It feels like this whole build infrastructure is absurdly unclear / overcomplicated"* - it is, and it gets worse. Wait until you get unknown/unexplained problems with `ant`. Or you can't figure out why a native library is not copied into the APK, or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's a mess.  It's messy because this single directory tree encompasses all of the organization needs of an IDE project, cross-compiling, and packaging and nobody within Android thought it was important to keep it clean.

If there are extra copies of your AndroidManifest.xml, ignore them.  They should just be part of the packaging process.

Think of `bin` as your output directory instead of simply for binaries.  The only thing you really care about in there is the apk.

`.d` is an extension most often used for directories.  So if a build process has to create a directory to hold files which help direct later steps according to a single input file, then it can just name the directory after the input file and slap a `.d` on it.

`gen` is generated as part of the build process.  It is safe to delete, but you usually have no need to do so.

`libs` are local libraries that are needed for linking to your app.  There are cases when you'd drop a Java jar in there that you want to use.

`obj` is for object files created by the compiler.  These are needed by the linker to actually create your app's native binaries.  It's safe to delete these and rerun the compiler, but that's a full recompile you're doing.

`res` is for app resource files.  Some are required by Android, and you can add more files there that you would use in your Java code.

If you're using SDL 2.0, you should also have an `assets` directory that holds the data files which your native code references.

It does say that some of the build files are autogenerated...  but your build isn't what generates them.

I use Eclipse (grudgingly) to build my Android apps, but you can also use `ant`, `ndk-build`, and `adb` to do all the same stuff on the command line.